# Getting the pid's of a program line by line

Tags: shell, process

I can find the pid's of my program instances by issuing command like this:

```
pidof avconv
```

Which is giving me results

```
16616 16283 16279 16198 16175 16035 15073 14049 4922
```

But how can I output the same result line by line, like:

```
16616 
16283 
16279 
16198 
16175 
16035 
15073 
14049 
4922
```

Comment: Why? Note that command substitution or `xargs` will split as happily on space as it will on newline.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could parse the output with `sed`, as suggested by @Sobrique, or with `tr`:

```
pidof avconv | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Another approach would be to use `pgrep` instead:

```
$ pgrep avconv16616 
16283 
16279 
16198 
16175 
16035 
15073 
14049
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just get it that way in the first place...

```
ps -C avconv -o pid=
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `sed` to insert some linefeeds

```
pidof avconv | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

although perhaps a bigger question is - why do you need them on separate lines? It may be that there's a more appropriate answer.

Comment: I do `pidof avconv | tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: I think it's 6 of one, a half dozen of the other when it's single character swaps.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `tr` should be a little bit faster since it's working at the character level and not parsing regular expressions. For example, on a 9MB file, sed took 55 seconds while tr took 19.

Comment: Oh I won't argue with larger data sets the efficiency matters. For smaller, I'd say familiarity is what matters. I posted the `sed` solution, because that's the first that came to mind :)

Comment: @Sobrique, thank you for the answer. Working perfectly. By the way i need the pids in separate lines, for special purpose

Comment: Just bear in mind that often that special purpose is things like iterating each of the pids - so rather than tweaking output format, it's often desirable to tweak input format.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it depending upon your need.

1. If you are doing it in a shell script

   ```
   for line in $(pidof avconv)
   do
     echo $line
   done
   ```
2. If you are looking for a oneliner

   ```
   pidof avconv |perl -pne 's|\s+|\n|g'
   ```

Comment: Both options works perfectly and reliably... but it's a bit of an overkill :-)

Comment: @FranklinPiat you are correct. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `pidof` on a Linux system, it may be possible to tell the utility to use a newline as the delimiter instead of space using its `-d` option:

```bash
pidof -d $'\n' /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this as well

```
ps ax | grep "program name, or part of it"
```

You will get the right answer, but also a meaningless entry like:

```
11424 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto something
```

Using `awk` to show only PID's:

```
ps ax | grep "program name, or part of it"| awk '{print $1}'
```

That will give you the PID's, but also the PID of the meaningles entry. This entry is usually the last, so just leave it out.

Comment: Grepping `ps` is very unreliable, as you may grep on unxpected fields (substring match of program name, file path, process status, tty...). `ps -C avconv` would be a better option here.

Comment: True. It takes the paths into account on some occasions. Well it can do the job under most circuimatances.